# How to remove old versions of iPhone SDK when installing the new one?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have downloaded iPhone SDK 4.0.2, I wanted to install it, but it looks that I don't have enough space. This made me think that maybe I could unistall the previous versions of iPhone SDK and install only the newest one.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Should I keep the old versions? Is there any situation they could be useful?

Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should you remove old versions? Up to you. You'll certainly have a "clean" installation. Do whatever you think is best for you. (You might want to reboot your system after uninstalling.)

Paul Peelen linked the command line step to do the removal, but I'm going to quote ad verbatim from Apple's "About Xcode.pdf" since the link could disappear:

> **Uninstalling Xcode Developer Tools**
>
> To uninstall Xcode developer tools on the
>   boot volume along with the 
>   directory, from a Terminal window
>   type:
>
> `$ sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools -mode=all`
>
> To remove the underlying developer content on the boot volume,
>   but leave the  directory and
>   supporting files untouched, from a
>   Terminal window type:
>
> `$ sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=systemsupport`
>
> To just remove the UNIX development support on the
>   boot volume, but leave the 
>   directory and supporting files
>   untouched, from a Terminal window
>   type:
>
> `$ sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=unixdev`
>
> Finally, to just uninstall the  directory you
>   can simply drag it to the trash, or
>   from a Terminal window type:
>
> `$ sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=xcodedir`
>
> **NOTE:** The uninstaller that ships with previous versions of
>   the Xcode developer tools will not
>   clean everything off of your system
>   properly. You should use the one
>   installed with these Xcode developer
>   tools.

(Those are current at least as of "Xcode 3.2.3 for Mac OS X 10.6 and iPhone OS 4.0")

Answer (score 1):

You can use appzapper, or just remove the stuff in /Developer/Applications (I believe).

Edit:
Asked my friend google, and this is what it came up with: http://macdevelopertips.com/xcode/how-to-uninstall-xcode.html

Comment: But is it a recommended practice to remove previous versions of the SDK? Are there any drawbacks? btw. I don't necessary want to remove XCode, but only the SDKs.

Comment: What the new version would do is replace the current version, if I am not misstaken. So I don't think there are any drawbacks. 
If you use appzapper, I think the any special preferences you might have set will get removed as well... otherwise It's good to go.

If you remove xcode, you might have enough space to install the 4.0.2 SDK. XCode will be installed again and the SDK's will be replaced.

Comment: So is new SDK really 7 GB big? Everytime I install new version of SDK it is huge, this is what made me think of removing the old versions.

Comment: No, the installation is that big because of a new XCode, IB and other tools. Those have updates as well if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but really 7 GB? It's not whole new XCode, I would even say that with SDK 4.0.1. I got XCode 3.2.3. installed and the same version was shipped with 4.0.2.

Comment: Well, in that case try to uncheck the xcode option in the installer when installing it. If you can, you won't have to install it. If you can't... you will have to. I myself still run the 4.0.1 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The new iOS SDK overwrites most of the old one (unless you change the installation directory), so it doesn't really double the disk space usage.